# git push branch, omitting one commit, but locally keep all

Tags: git

I created a local branch (B1) off of master, and made a change necessary to get the project working on my local machine, then committed that.  Then I began to work on a new issue, so I checked out a new branch (B2) off of B1, and have so far made two commits there.

```
                      o -- o B2
                     / 
                    o B1
                   /
-- o -- o -- o -- o master
```

Now I would like to push the results of my code fixes so that my boss and other coworkers can look at them, but I do not want to send them that first change I made, as they do not need that fix, their local setups are different.  My initial thought is to rebase B2 onto master, skipping that lone commit in B1:

```
git rebase -p --onto master <SHA-of-B1-commit> B2
```

but this would leave me with a version of B2 that doesn't include the change on B1 at all, meaning the project would again not work correctly on my local machine.

Is there any way to push the changes from B2, while still retaining both B1 and B2 locally?

Comment: Bigger question:  why does your environment require the fix?

Comment: It's a global.asa file - my computer has the website installed in a different directory than the production server, so I had to change global.asa's VRoot.

Comment: Why not move your configuration to mimic production's as closely as you can?  This way, you don't have to worry about committing configuration like this.

Comment: Honest answer?  Because I don't understand enough about IIS configurations to know how to move my website files to the directory specified in the production global.asa, without royally screwing everything up. 
(And yes, I realize the irony in asking how to do one thing because I don't understand correctly how to do another thing...)

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a third branch?

```
git checkout -b B3 B2
git cherry-pick <required commit1> <required commit2> ...
git push <remote> B3:B2
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this would effectively mean I'd have two separate and distinct versions of B2, one local and one public.  And any time I make any changes on the B2 branch (or its children), I'd have to cherry-pick those changes to B3 as well.  Is that accurate?  While it's certainly doable, I was hoping to find a solution that allowed me to have that B1 commit on my machine only, and all other current and future commits on B2 both locally and remotely.

Comment: Your determination is correct, you'd have to re-pick subsequent B2 commits and you'd technically have two branches.